# Infinite Scroll and Social Media Buttons

Tags: javascript, wordpress, infinite-scroll

I am using Infinite-Scroll on my website [Car Show News](http://3d-car-shows.com/car-news/)

I am also using Masonry on the site to arrange the posts

Here is an example of the JavaScript I am using to call the masonry and infinite-scroll scripts...

```
$(function () {
var $container = $('.main');
$container.imagesLoaded(function () {
    $container.masonry({
        itemSelector: '.post',
        isAnimated: true
    });
});
$('.main').infinitescroll({
    navSelector: ".post-nav",
    nextSelector: ".previous a",
    itemSelector: ".post",
    loadingImg: "http://b.imagehost.org/0548/Untitled-2.png",
    loadingText: "<em></em>",
    onPageChange: function (pageNum, pageUrl, scrollOffset) {
        path = jQuery('<a/>').attr('href', pageUrl)[0].pathname.replace(/^[^\/]/, '/');
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', path]);
    }
}, function (newElements) {
    var $newElems = $(newElements).css({
        opacity: 0
    });
    $newElems.imagesLoaded(function () {
        $newElems.animate({
            opacity: 1
        });
        $container.masonry('appended', $newElems, true);
    });
    var el = document.getElementById('gsocial');
    if (typeof gapi !== "undefined") {
        gapi.plusone.go(el);
    }
    if (typeof FB !== "undefined") {
        FB.XFBML.parse(el);
    }
    if (typeof twttr !== "undefined") {
        twttr.widgets.load();
    }
}); });`
```

When loading the social media buttons the Facebook button seems to load all the Facebook buttons again after scrolling down and using the infinite scroll script...

**What do I need to do to stop the script from loading the facebook button again and again?**